# Iron Out and CLR mixed - toxic gas?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Someone I know mixed the liquid forms of Iron Out and CLR (Calcium, Lime, & Rust Remover) together to clean out a plastic bathtub.

I have the SDS sheets for each:

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dkhh0JXRL.pdf - CLR
https://summitbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Iron-OUT-liquid-English-GHS-Rev-01-29-18.pdf - Iron Out

The bathroom smells terrible, has produced a cough in the person using it, and now my eye burns a little from very brief contact. I was wondering what kind of gas (if any) was created when these two chemical cleaners were mixed?

Comment: Lactic Acid, Gluconic Acid, Lauramine Oxide for the CLR. Sodium hydrosulfite, Sodium carbonate, Sodium metabisulfite, Citric Acid, Sodium sulfite for the Iron Out which was actually the powder version rather than liquid version.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, [sulfur dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_dioxide). $\ce{SO2}$. was produced. The ingredients sodium hydrosulfite, $\ce{Na2S2O4}$, and sodium metabisulfite, $\ce{Na2S2O5}$, when mixed with acid, release $\ce{SO2}$, which oxidizes to $\ce{SO3}$ eventually.

$\ce{SO2}$ is quite irritating, but not *immediately* damaging in low doses, <100 ppm, though it can certainly induce a life-threatening [asthma](http://www.asthmaed.com/journal/2015/7/27/sulphur-dioxide-and-asthma) attack. "Sulfur dioxide is mildly toxic and can be hazardous in high concentrations. Long-term exposure to low concentrations is also problematic." $\ce{SO3}$ is even more dangerous, since it forms sulfuric acid when it meets water, e.g. in tears in the eye.

**Air the room *thoroughly.** There is not much else to do: theoretically, ammonia could be used to form a salt, removing the gas from air, but there is no way you could balance the reaction, leaving you with an excess of one irritant or another.

Comment: I will try my best to air it out, the room is closed off and only has a bathroom air exhaust fan, which is mostly just for removing moisture. Given that the Iron Out and CLR is approximately 15 years or older, I am hoping that they lost potency. In addition, not a lot of it was used, though enough to notice. I will try running a fan in the bathroom and a second fan in the hallway to the living room with open windows. Thank you for the help, hopefully this works.

Comment: At least SO2 gives ample warning -- it's not subtle. Once the annoying odor is gone, the room should be safe for long-term residency. My guess is that the exhaust fan should be effective in less than a day.